# Drupal 7 - как на Views 3 построить отчет по нодам, связанным через Node reference

Tags: drupal, views

Доброго дня!
Разрабатываю сайт на Drupal 7. На нём имеются:

- Типы материала "Статья" и "Новость", содержащие текст и картинки
- Тип материала "Баннер", предоставляемая модулем SimpleAds
- Словарь таксономии "Место размещения баннера", также предоставляемый модулем SimpleAd. Содержит 7 терминов по числу мест в макете.

В баннер добавлены поля: 
 - ссылка типа Node reference на статью/новость, в которой баннер должен отображаться
 - ссылка на термин из словаря "Место размещения", указывающая, где именно на странице новости/статьи должен отобразиться баннер
 - дата начала отображения баннера.
Отображением баннера занимается SimpleAds, привязкой к макету - Views и блоки.

Задача:
Сформировать таблицу (отчет) по местам размещения баннеров, в котором было бы видно заполненные и пустые места в статьях. Таблица должна содержать следующие поля:

1. URL статьи,
2. Дата начала отображения баннера на месте 1
3. Дата начала отображения баннера на месте 2
4. Дата начала отображения баннера на месте 3
5. Дата начала отображения баннера на месте 4
6. Дата начала отображения баннера на месте 5
7. Дата начала отображения баннера на месте 6
8. Дата начала отображения баннера на месте 7

С каждой статьёй может быть связано несколько баннеров (как на одном и том же месте, что неправильно, так и на разных местах). В случае нескольких баннеров на одном месте интересует самый "старый". Если ни одного баннера на каком-либо месте нет - поле остается пустым.

Как я пытаюсь эту задачу решить:

1. построить представление "в лоб" с помощью Views и контекстных фильтров. Не могу найти возможности
   прицепить несколько связанных баннеров по ссылкам Node Reference,
   профильтрованных по термину таксономии, указанному в них. Агрегировать все без относительно терминов и посчитать их количество - тоже да. Так как
   надо - увы
2. допилить модуль Nodereference Count, чтобы он фильтровал баннеры по
   таксономии и хранил даты в соответствующих полях, а не количество.
   Не осилил. Да и идея хранить данные по связанным сущностям во
   внутренних полях ноды выглядит избыточной - хочется формирования на
   лету.
3. сделать собственное поле и views api handler для вычислений по
   примерам из гитхаба. Не смог понять как заставить его агрегировать
   (пример с Views API v2 не завелся вообще, v3 поле видит, но не
   возвращает данные).

Собственные поля видятся самым правильным решением, т.к. в дальнейшем этот отчет надо будет расширять, модифицировать, а данные из него выгружать в Excel. Views для этого подходит больше всего.

Подскажите, как эту задачу можно решать на Views?

Answer (score 0):

Решение - модуль [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view)  (+ [Views content cache](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_content_cache) для кеширования)

Опишу подробнее, что нужно сделать для решения. Я использую русификацию интерфейса, так что привожу термины и названия полей в текущей версии их перевода.

Сначала нужно сделать "Дочернее" представление (7 шт. дисплеев, на каждом отбирается только одно баннерное место):

- Выбор всех материалов типа "Статья"
- Формат - поля. "Обязательная" связь по полю Node reference.
- Контекстный фильтр с указанием этой связи, принимающий ID статьи
  (если значение не представлено - передать ID материала из URL).
- Поле с подсчетом (count distinct), из которого убрана метка и классы
  оформления.
- Критерий фильтрации по месту (на каждом из 7    дисплеев -
  свой тип).

Потом - "Родительское" представление

- Формат вывода - таблица Поле Заголовок (ссылкой на материал)
- Поле Nid (скрытое)
- 7 полей типа "Глобальный: Просмотр", в настройках указать название "Дочернего" представления и первый по счету дисплей, значение контекстного фильтра [nid]